# Qtip tooltips not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, tooltip

I made the navbar on the top of my page static (the rest of the page is dynamic)

The navbar is in a div that is given the ID "header" and and everything else is in a div with the ID "main".

I use this code to make tooltips.

This is the Javascript/jquery/qtip

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Tooltips
    $(".tiptrigger").hover(function(){
        tip = $(this).find('.tip');
        tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    }, function() {
        tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
        var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
        var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

        //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
        var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
        //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
        var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

        if (tipVisX < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
            mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
        } if (tipVisY < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
            mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
        }
        //Absolute position the tooltip according to mouse position
        tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
//Tooltips
    $(".tipheader").hover(function(){
        tip = $(this).find('.tip');
        tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    }, function() {
        tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 30; //Get X coodrinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + -20; //Get Y coordinates
        var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
        var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

        //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
        var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
        //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
        var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

        if (tipVisX < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
            mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
        } if (tipVisY < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
            mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
        }
        //Absolute position the tooltip according to mouse position
        tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
    });
});
```

Then this is the CSS

```
.tip {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1d1d1d;
    display: none; /*--Hides by default--*/
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;    
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

This is the HTML that calls the tooltip.
The first line is for the main section, the second is for the header.

```
<a href="LINK URL" class="tiptrigger"><img src="IMAGE URL" alt="" /><span class="tip">CONTENT</span></a>
<a href="LINK URL" class="tipheader"><img src="IMAGE URL" alt="" /><span class="tip">CONTENT</span></a>
```

The reason I used two different javascript sections is because the tooltips in the header and the tooltips in the main section needed different parameters.

Now, the problem is that the tooltips work fine in the header, but they're not working in the main section and I can't think of any possible reason why, I tried everything I could think of and it's not working. Does anyone else know how to fix it?

Comment: You don't need two `$(document).ready` functions.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tz59G/

Can you verify that the event handlers for the .tiptrigger elements are firing?  Perhaps place a couple of `console.log()` statements in your functions.  Then you can start narrowing it down to either a javascript, CSS, or markup problem.

Comment: @ Jack, okay, I changed it so it only has one $(document).ready but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RocooC5. How do I do that? I don't know anything about console.log()

Comment: @RoccoC5 also, I edited your jsFiddle to contain the main and header divs like I explained above, and now it doesn't work, but I don't know why.  http://jsfiddle.net/tz59G/2/

Comment: @Mark Kramer - Regarding `console.log()`: some browsers support the this function as a convenient means to debug your client-side code. Check out Firebug for FireFox or the developer tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix it by setting the #header div to fixed positioning (so it stays at the top of the window without absolute positioning) and I made the #main div static positioned and moved it down with just page breaks.

*I decided it would be more efficient to only use one type of tooltip, so I removed one.
*Note how I set the min-height so I can display how the #header div stays at the top when you scroll, that is the effect I wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/tz59G/5/

to see the finished result, go here: ultimatemmo.webege.com

The navbar on top is my header div and everything else is my main div.

Note: that site isn't a normal traffic site, I made it for a school project, now it's just a personal project that I'm constantly improving. The only reason it's on the internet is so my friends and girlfriend can see my progress on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need absolute positioning on your `div` elements (it doesn't appear so since you aren't specifying any `top` or `left` values)?  Since the tooltip uses absolute positioning and is nested within another element which *also uses absolute positioning*, it can't "break out" from the parent element.

I recommend that you remove the `position: absolute` rule from the `#header` and `#main` styles.  Alternatively, removing the `overflow: auto` rule from the `#header` style seems to work as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/tz59G/3/

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but the point is that I can't take off the absolute positioning, that changes my page entirely, I need to find a way to make the tooltips work with the divs on absolute positioning

Comment: Oh wow, I just noticed that the tooltip does show up in the main section, it's just way higher than it should be. Can you think of any explanation for that?

Comment: I got it, I made the header div fixed positioned and the main section relative positioned and then it worked beautifully =) Thanks for letting me know that the problem was the absolute positioning